# Post single notification with varying object types

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a class that acts as a wrapper around AVPlayer, and one of the functions it serves is to post notifications every 1 and 10 seconds during playback (ie make `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:` more convenient in the general case).

Previously, the object I was sending with this notification was the player wrapper itself (ie ABPlayer.sharedPlayer). Today I had the need to allow for some objects to only receive notifications about a specific media item's playback. This can be accomplished by sending `[[someAVURLAsset URL] absoluteString]` as the notification object (when the asset in the `AVPlayer` is an `AVURLAsset`, of course).

The prompted the question: is it appropriate for a single notification to, in different situations, post with different *types* of objects? I understand the value in sending specific objects or sending `nil` (catch-all), but I don't recall seeing a situation where an alternative type of object could be sent. In my case, though, it seems to make sense.

I could simply send two distinct notifications, but since these are always only ever being sent to notify observers of a single event, and they are always being sent from the same place in code, they simply feel like a single notification.

I realize what I have is possible and working, but I'm curious if there's a compelling reason to avoid this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the scenarios in which the different object types will be sent to the observers are well understood *and documented*, there's no technical reason why you can't do it. It may make more contextual sense to post a different notification for each object type. It would certainly help any developers who may end up maintaining your code.